# Named location as fallback in try_files directive

Tags: nginx

I'm having problem wrapping my head around routing processing in Nginx.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my_domain;

    root /var/www/ep;

    index index.html;

    error_page 403 404 /my403.html;

    location /images/ {
            try_files $uri @not_found;
    }

    location @not_found {
            root /var/www/ep/not_found;
            try_files NON_EXISTENT_1 /not_found.jpg;
    }
}
```

For above config, when I visit http://my_domain/images/xyz.png or http://my_domain/images/ I expect `@not_found` location directive to take place returning an image from `/var/www/ep/not_found/not_found.jpg` (it exists) but somehow `/var/www/ep/not_found.jpg` path is being tried (it doesn't exist). It results in displaying `/my403.html` file.

I want to use named location approach (`@not_found`).

Could somebody explain what's happening here?

Why `/var/www/ep/not_found/not_found.jpg` is not served?

Answer (score 0):

You place `/not_found.jpg` at the end of the `try_files` statement, which makes it the URI term, which means `nginx` will search for a new `location` to process the request. You should make it **not** last, for example:

```
try_files /not_found.jpg =404;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

---

As an alternative to a named `location`, you could use:

```
location /images/ {
        try_files $uri /not_found.jpg;
}
location = /not_found.jpg {
    root /var/www/ep/not_found;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Thanks Richard for responding. 
I'm trying out this named location approach (I updated the question to make it visible) instead of "make it work somehow". I'm learning, I don't prefer quick fix.